# Regex in Golang: How to set character that makes the string not match?

Tags: regex, go, escaping, backslash

I am a noob about regular expressions (sorry).
I was trying to make a very simple markup language that matches bold and italic and then converts them to HTML.
Here is an example for bold that I'm using:

```
var bold = regexp.MustCompile("\\*([^\\*]+)\\*")
```

It matches everything between two asterisks. Now, I'd like it to match `*test*` but not `\*test*`. Since I don't know much about regular expressions but I'm trying to make this experiment, I'd like to know what's the way for that. I searched everywhere but couldn't find the way to make this work.

Comment: The issue here is that in case you have `\\*test*` the approach won't work. You should write a parser for this task, do not use regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated***

Go does not support lookbehinds. So a workaround can be:

```
(?:\A|(?:[^\\]+|\A)(\\{2})+|[^\\])\*([^\\*]+)\*
```

Comment: This regex won't match `\\*test*`  while this `test` appears in between valid `*` delimiters. One cannot rely on 1-regex solution when parsing strings with escape sequences.

Comment: Why should it match `\\*test*`? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Because ``\\`` is a literal ``\``, and then comes `*test*` that should be matched.

Comment: Let poster go further for additional information about entries. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I'll be writing a parser for this then...

Comment: I don't think a parser is essential for this specific task. Based on Wiktor comments I just updated my answer. @altermetax